# How to set up Symbol Server for both C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, debugging, symbols, symbol-server

Microsoft provided a solution that allows one to easily manage and retrieve symbol files for his code using symbol server.

We are use both c# and Java, and I was wondering if there is a way to setup something similar to Symbol Server for Java, and is it possible to make it the same server.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're talking about repository managers and source code artifacts. If so - there are two common options - Nexus and Artifactory. You can read about the difference between them [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/01/03/tale-two-repository-managers-nexus-and-artifactory-compared-and-co). I never used Artifactory, but I can guarantee that with Nexus and Maven configured you can easily retrieve code or other artifacts from a central repository.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the reference and if it answers the question I will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi, Actually I do not see how these tools will solve my problem. When if I set a Microsoft Symbol Server, I can easily set it up as http server and when I need to debug from a clients machine, i just give the symserver path to the debugger and it automatically gets the right symbols for the specific build. I do not see how I can use the tools you mentioned to do that, it seems they require a lot of manual work to achieve that every time.

Comment: Did you ever had chance to work with Maven and java? If configured properly the IDE will automatically download sources or whatever you need from the repositories specified.